# Missing Requirement Error while installing PDT in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: php, eclipse

I have a PHP project which I develop in Eclipse and very hard to identify PHP codes as PHP plugin in not there in my eclipse. I need to install a PHP plugin where I tried to install PDT from Eclipse Marketplace and getting following errors:

**Missing Requirement: PDT Smart Importer Plug-in requires bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.12.0.**

where it looks like this PDT version cannot be install in my current Eclipse Indigo version.

Please need your help how can I install PDT in my Eclipse Indigo. I have attached the error screenshots.

[image]

**Note:** I have checked other stackoverflow posts regarding similar error which I tried and not working and few links are missing from eclipse website.

Comment: Eclipse Indigo is **seven** years old so it is probably too old to run this code.

Comment: Yes. I agree @greg-449 . I think this is the best solution should be. Mainly, I was thinking if there is any workaround solution is possible in this version. Thank you so much.

Comment: I installed Eclipse Oxygen.2 and looks all well. Thanks a ton.